# How to parse JSONP with PHP

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract JSONP Resultset in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081557/extract-jsonp-resultset-in-php)

I get the response in the following format. Im facing trouble on how to get inside "Plugin" variable and access other variables inside it.I used `json_decode()`, but i cant access the variables.

```
Plugin
(
{ 

"plugin_a":"abc", 
"plugin_b":"abc", 
"plugin_c":"abc" 
}
)
```

I tried

```
$a = json_decode($json,true);
echo  $a['plugin_a'];
```

I dont get any output.

`echo var_dump($json);`  gives me

```
string 'Plugin({
  "plugin_a":"abc",
  "plugin_b":"abc",
  "plugin_ce":"abc" })'
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON...

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick response...this code solved by problem  http://codepad.org/eJXeaXIO

Answer (score 0):

try substr();

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/40c20.php

```
<?php
$json = substr('Plugin
(
{ 

"plugin_a":"abc", 
"plugin_b":"abc", 
"plugin_c":"abc" 
}
)', 9, -1);

print_r(json_decode($json));
```

Comment: a more general approach would be to preg_match everything between the the first opening ( and last closing ).

Comment: Thanks...this code solved my problem. http://codepad.org/eJXeaXIO

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
$data=array('plugin_a'=>'abc','plugin_b'=>'bcd','plugin_c'=>'cde');
$json='{"Plugin":'.json_encode($data).'}';
$a=json_decode($json,true);
echo $a['Plugin']['plugin_a'];
```

It appears as though the actual json array may not have integrity.  If this solution doesn't fit, can you post the code that actually builds the json array?