# Parse JSONP with R

Tags: r, jsonp

Building on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r), can R parse JSONP objects?  I have successfully been using `RJSONIO` to read/parse JSON objects from the web.

I encountered a feed that is JSONP.  When I attempted to use `fromJSON()`, an empty list is returned.

Any help will be very much appreciated.  Staying within R is preferred.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse JSONP content, you can strip away the function call that is wrapped around the JSON content (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5081588/489704) in the context of PHP), and then parse the content as you would for standard JSON.

To do this in R, try something along the lines of:

```
j  <- readLines('http://live.nhl.com/GameData/20112012/2011020908/Roster.jsonp')
j <- sub('[^\\{]*', '', j) # remove function name and opening parenthesis
j <- sub('\\)$', '', j) # remove closing parenthesis
library(RJSONIO)
res <- fromJSON(j)

# example output:
unlist(lapply(res$data$home$skaters$player, function(x) x$lname))
 [1] "Greene"       "Zubrus"       "Parise"       "Ponikarovsky"
 [5] "Henrique"     "Sykora"       "Josefson"     "Kovalchuk"   
 [9] "Bernier"      "Carter"       "Harrold"      "Clarkson"    
[13] "Salvador"     "Janssen"      "Elias"        "Volchenkov"  
[17] "Fayne"        "Taormina"
```

I'm not that familiar with JSON, nor JSONP, so I'm not sure if it's possible to encounter JSONP content with multiple function call wrappers. If so, you'll need to modify the `sub` pattern somewhat. If you'd like to point me to your JSONP feed, I can amend this solution accordingly. RJSONIO might also offer easier ways to extract list elements than `lapply`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  http://live.nhl.com/GameData/20112012/2011020908/Roster.jsonp