# Having issues parsing json

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract JSONP Resultset in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081557/extract-jsonp-resultset-in-php)

```
    $url_address = "http://geocoder.ca/?latt=" . $lat . "&longt=" . $lon . "&reverse=1&allna=1&geoit=xml&corner=1&jsonp=1&callback=getinfo";
    $addressSet = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_address), true);
```

When I try to to access `$addressSet[0]` is does not have anything

So the http://geocoder.ca/?latt=42.04&longt=-87.79&reverse=1&allna=1&geoit=xml&corner=1&jsonp=1&callback=getinfo returns data, how can I parse it?

Comment: You need a regex to extract the JSON first, then process it further. (PHP "parses" it, btw, you just "traverse" the resulting array strucutre.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not returning JSON, it's returning [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Unfortunately geocoder.ca doesn't have a plain JSON API.

The real question is how to parse JSONP with PHP. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5081588/253686) to [Extract JSONP Resultset in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081557/extract-jsonp-resultset-in-php)