# PHP: Handling 'JSONP' output vs 'JSON', and its parsing?

Tags: php, callback, jsonp, decode

**I am having a problem parsing 'jsonp' request with php's `json_decode` function.**

My questions is

**a. *What is the use of call back function in 'jsonp', should i just trip that off, or am I suppose to use it in some manner. ?***

**b. *How can I rectify the syntax error received in 'jsonp' format ?***

Below I have given the code and the response that I get.

**1.** I request a sample url with PHP's curl

```
$url = 'https://ssl.domain.com/data/4564/d.jsonp';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");     
$feed = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $feed =  gzdecode($feed); // Success its displays the jsonp feed
```

**2.** Then I try to json_decode the received output, which throws the error no 4 meaning [JSON_SYNTAX_ERROR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php#106644), the reason I guess is because names of string type in jsonp are not quoted. e.g. `Categories`, `Name`, `Position` etc.

```
$json_feed = json_decode($feed);
$error = json_last_error(); 
echo $error;     // Throws error no. 4
```

**3.** RAW 'jsonp' output from the url.

```
domain_jsonp_callback({
   Categories:[
      {
         Name:"Artifacts",
         Position:14,
         Count:70,
         ImageUrls:{
            i100:"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/1.png",
            i120:"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/2.png",
            i140:"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/3.png",
            i180:"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/4.png",
            i220:"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/5.png",
            i280:"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/6.png"
         }
      }
   ]
});
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5081588/1788516

Comment: @Perry, thanks I did saw that answer, but is there any reason why the responding server sends the callback function. That callback function must be serving some purpose right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the use of call back function in 'jsonp', should i just trip that off, or am I suppose to use it in some manner. ?

JSON-P is really a JavaScript script that consists of a function call with an argument.

If you want to parse it in PHP, then yes, you need to strip it off. You also need to strip off the `);` at the end.

> b. How can I rectify the syntax error received in 'jsonp' format ?

You need to fix the data so it really is JSON. The data you have is a JavaScript literal, but it doesn't conform to the subset of JavaScript that matches JSON (e.g. property names are not strings but must be).

It would be better to get a real JSON resource form the source instead.

Comment: that clarifies something will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Callback function is for JS calls - it allows to use API's in AJAX manner, without taking care of same origin policy. When JSONP call is used in JS - browser just calls the **callback function** that needs to be defined on API client's side.

When you use JSONP inside PHP callback function is not needed at all. If server supports raw JSON type calls - use it, if not strip the callback function strings, in your case

```
$jsonData = json_decode(substr($feed, 22, -2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about it but i think names should also be quoted  like this:

```
domain_jsonp_callback({
   Categories:[
      {
         "Name":"Artifacts",
         "Position":14,
         "Count":70,
         "ImageUrls":{
            "i100":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/1.png",
            "i120":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/2.png",
            "i140":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/3.png",
            "i180":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/4.png",
            "i220":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/5.png",
            "i280":"//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.domain.com/6.png"
         }
      }
   ]
});
```

PS: Probably "Categories" too :?

Comment: I thought that would be taken care by the responding server, unfortunately its not. Is there a way that it can be managed with some php function.

Comment: Well... the raw data comes as string, seems wrong but u can edit it like any other string. (there should be a better way to do this) You can try reading it line by line exploding it on ":" and setting the first element to have quotes and rewriting it into another string, which will be valid JSON...

Comment: thank will try that as last resort, as that be tedious on server to process everytime user request a page.