# Parsing non standard JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

This is a non standard `json` format api :

```
   WebInfo ({
    "name": "Google",
    "code": 1,
    "domain": "http://www.google.com/",
    })
```

as the data is not a standard JSON, `json_decode()` can not be resolved directly, what can I do to make it become a valid `json` format ?

Comment: Can you provide some code so I can understand the context? What are you trying to do? What have you already done? The key value pairs in the `{}` is valid JSON.

Comment: i want remove the 'WebInfo' and () .

Comment: Where is this value coming from? Will the value always stay in this format?

Comment: You have a error in your json. Remove the `,` after `"http://www.google.com/"`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I didn't even notice that, but that still will not allow him to use the `json_decode()` php method because he has the WebInfo prefix.

Comment: the value is get from a url using file_get_contents()

Comment: can you share the url so I can see the actual return?

Comment: This is [JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2067472/660921). Also see [Handling 'JSONP' output vs 'JSON', and its parsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17613140/660921).

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I was just about to post that.. :)

Comment: You need to replace the values as @AniketSahrawat said.

Comment: What? which values are you talking about @McStuffins

Comment: `WebInfo(` and `)`

Comment: Why how can it be done then?

Comment: .. Im agreeing with you.

Comment: OOPsie sorry my bad I didn't read the comment @McStuffins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to strip out `WebInfo (` and `)` which can be done by using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Try this: Lets assume your string that has `WebInfo({...})` is `$str` then do this:

```
$str = str_replace('WebInfo(', '', $str); 
$str = str_replace(' )', '', $str);
print_r(json_decode($str, true));
```

**WARNING:** `str_replace()` will strip out every character mentioned from the string. Eg: if I use something like

```
str_replace('hello', 'hi', $str);
```

Then it will replace every `hello` to `hi` in `$str`.

Comment: This will end in some funny results as soon as you have something like `MusicInfoCallback(` or ` )` in the name or the domain fields or as soon as there is no leading space before the ")" (e.g. caused by different line breaks on different systems). `str_replace` is definitely **not** the right tool for this task.

Comment: According to [this](https://s007-outspa74225.c9users.io/test.php), there is a space before `)` @Quasdunk

Comment: @AniketSahrawat and according to what there is never a " )" in the name or domain or whatever else there migh be?

Comment: I agree with you but in this case there is no other element enclosed inside `()` otherwise you will need `regex` for removing and that is why i upvoted your answer @Quasdunk

Comment: Or, just use `substr`, because that's exactly the purpose of it. `str_replace` is for, well, *replacing strings*, `substr` is for extracting a substring - which is exactly what you want to do. Both tools serve different purposes, so why on earth would you eat a soup with a fork (which may work) if there is a spoon right next to you? Your answer may work in this particular case, but then you at least should mention the caveats!

Comment: @Quasdunk I thought that is already mentioned in your answer and hence no need to show it in a separate answer. You can make the changes to my answer if you want. Just watch for extra spaces after `)` if there are any

Comment: I'm not talking about any caveats in my answer, because with those approaches you don't need to care about it. I'm talking about the outcome of your code if e.g. the `name` was "Google ( my favorite search engine )". You would actually alter the payload data (!!!) which is absolutely not what you want and which could be avoided easily by using the right tools for this task. And I think you should at least mention that.

Comment: I think you are right. I will add a warning that `str_replace` will strip out every `)` @Quasdunk

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little JSONP-ish, so it actually should be valid JSON, except that it's wrapped within a funtion call. But that comma at the end of `"domain": "http://www.google.com/",` sure does not belong there.

You have several ways to go about it:

1. **strip the function wrapper**

This only works if you know the function name. So if you know that it'll always be wrapped with `WebInfo(...)`, you could just extract the JSON-part substring:

```
$jsonPart = substr($jsonpString, 8, -1);
```

where 8 is the length of "WebInfo(" and "-1" takes care of the ")" at the end.

2. **Parse the JSON-part**

Simply parse everything between the first "{" and the last "}":

```
preg_match("/\{(.*)\}/s", $jsonpString, $matches);
```

Since there should only be one match, you grab the first:

```
$jsonPart = $matches[0];
```

With this approach you don't need to know the wrapper-function name's name/length. But still you need to take care of that trailing comma mentioned above. Is it really there or was it just a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: what is the difference between the 2 answers?

Comment: They would both work. you are essentially replacing the values with nothing. Looks the same to me. I haven't tested either solution, but they do the same thing.

Comment: @McStuffins But they don't. `str_replace` will replace *everything* including the actual payload. It may work in many, maybe most cases, but it's strictly tied to some assumptions that can easily change without your influence. It is simply not a good / robust approach. What if tha name is "Google ( my favorite search engine )"?