# How can i get the value of array in php?

Tags: php, json

This is my array. as you notice it has `response` because i use it on JSONP

How can get the value of the json using PHP?

this is my code :

```
      foreach ($apiResults['contacts'] as $contact=>$cs) {
          foreach ($apiResults['conference_participants'] as $conference_participant=>$c) {

            if ($c['name'] == $cs['name']) {
              unset($apiResults['contacts'][$contact]);
            }

          }
       }
```

Comment: Tried with `json_decode();` ?

Comment: ^^ As all of the comment above mine suggested the answer. So did you gave it a try?

Comment: yes @Uchiha Madara . I refer on this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081557/extract-jsonp-resultset-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081557/extract-jsonp-resultset-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not yet able to write a comment, so i'll try to write it as an answer.
`json_decode` will not return a value because your json string is containing callback function `response()` which is not a valid json string.

You'll need to remove the callback function name `response(` and the trailing `)`.

example:

`$array = json_decode(substr( $jsonp, 8, -1 ));
// $jsonp is your server jsonp response`