# unable to decode json via php from url

Tags: php, json

I am trying to read json vi php but unable to decode

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/AAPL/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/json";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: You also can find some general solution for decoding JSONP on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081557/extract-jsonp-resultset-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you visit your target URL you will notice the JSON value is wrapped in a 
callback method which you could trim as by something like

```
$json = str_replace('finance_charts_json_callback(', '', substr($pageContent, 0, strlen($pageContent) - 1));
```

Here is how it looks all put together:

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/AAPL/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/json"; $pageContent = file_get_contents($json_url);

$json = str_replace('finance_charts_json_callback(', '', substr($pageContent, 0, strlen($pageContent) - 1));

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: thank ali,it worked, can you help me little more, how can fetch last value of $data 'series' 'close' after every 5 min, not asking to code it for me, just an idea.

Comment: Let me have a look at the data and get back to you

Comment: So something like `$lastOfSeries = end($data['series']);`  will store the last item from the series into the $lastOfSeries variable

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is work with it in JavaScript:

```
<script>
function finance_charts_json_callback(json){
    console.log(json.meta);
}
</script>

<?php 
$json_url = "http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/AAPL/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/json";
$data = file_get_contents($json_url);

echo "<script>";
print_r($data);
echo "</script>";
?>
```

Other thing is try to remove the 'function' part:

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/AAPL/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/json";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json = substr($json, 30);
$json = substr($json, 0, strlen($json)-2);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The response from this service is not a valid JSON object its JSONP, you should look for a service that provides output as JSON.

In case they don't provide a service like that you can manipulate the data before decoding it using this workaround

```
$data = str_replace('finance_charts_json_callback( ', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(' )', '', $data);
```