# Convert String to Json in PHP from GET Request

Tags: php, json, api

When run GET request, the site returns a string instead of JSON with a question mark in the beginning of the string.

```
?({ "Years": {"min_year":"1941", "max_year":"2017"} });
```

I tried to use **json_encode()** function in PHP. However, it returns *NULL*.

The results is from this site: https://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getYears

Does anyone know how to convert the result into JSON? Thanks,

Comment: Because instead of `?` should be function name, I suppose. This is called `jsonp`

Comment: Would be an `encode`, not a `decode`.

Comment: @ficuscr. Sorry, it's a typo. I used encode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you grab the results from the URL without the `callback` parameter, you can get the standard JSON format.

https://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?cmd=getYears

`{ "Years": {"min_year":"1941", "max_year":"2017"} }`

Comment: Thanks, @Ben. Do you know why the callback function creates such a result?

Comment: They provided that to implement JSONP which was a workaround for Ajax calls that violate the Same origin Policy.  Since you are running server-side php code, it's not an issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially JSONP.  They are returning a function ?() with the JSON result inside of it.  You would need to remove the outer function, as [has been described previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081557/extract-jsonp-resultset-in-php).

They provided that to implement JSONP which was a workaround for Ajax calls that violate the Same origin Policy.  This [issue and technique is discussed here](https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/).

With that said, Ben has found that without the callback param you can avoid the whole issue.

Comment: Thanks @gview for the explanation.